# jQuery/JS getting nav menu to hide when the body if clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to get the slide out navigation menu (menuRight) to disappear when anything other than the menu itself is clicked.

Here is my JS:

```
var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
        menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
        menuBottom = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s4' ),
        // showLeft = document.getElementById( 'showLeft' ),
        showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
        showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
        showBottom = document.getElementById( 'showBottom' ),
        showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
        showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
        body = document.body;

        var a=document.getElementsByClassName('showLeft');
        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            a[i].onclick = function() {
            classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
            classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
            disableOther( 'showLeft' );
};

}

showLeft.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeft' );
};
showRight.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRight' );
};
showTop.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showTop' );
};
showBottom.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showBottom' );
};
showLeftPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeftPush' );
};
showRightPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
};

function disableOther( button ) {
    if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
        classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
        classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showTop' ) {
        classie.toggle( showTop, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showBottom' ) {
        classie.toggle( showBottom, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showLeftPush' ) {
        classie.toggle( showLeftPush, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRightPush' ) {
        classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
    }
}
```

This part here is the JQuery code that Im attempting to use (and which isn't working).

```
$(":not(#menuRight)").onclick = function() {
    disableOther( 'showLeft' );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try $("*").not("#menuRight").click(function(){//do something});

Comment: Sadly not working :/

Comment: Is the disableOther function working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event propagation to watch for a click event on the document (that is not within your menu).

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#menucontainer').length) {
    // Hide the menus.
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried testing this by creating a hidden div with the class 'test' and used: $(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#menuRight').length) {
    $('.test').show();
  }
}); It did not work.. Is that code correct?

Comment: Just got your code to work! Now the only thing that won't work is getting the actual menu to go... I don't quite know why it's not disappearing ?